# Тест не делает скриншот

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screenshots

Ниже приведённый код производит один снимок экрана, а после ничего не делает и не выдаёт ошибок. Почему так происходит?

```
class Menu(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.set_window_size(1300, 800)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    def take_screenshot(self):
        screen = str(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S'))
        self.driver.save_screenshot(screen + ".png")

    @staticmethod
    def men_recon():
        image = Image.open('men.gif')
        print(image_to_string(image))

    def test_menu(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://...')
```

Comment: Добавьте какой-нибудь `print(screen)` в take_screenshot и смотрите в консоли, что и сколько раз печатается (то есть вызывается ли take_screenshot)

Comment: @andreymal добавил. ничего не печатается.

Comment: переделал на вот так:
    def take_screenshot(self):
        self.driver.save_screenshot('my_screenshot.png')
        print('screen')

Comment: Ну тут ещё возможно, что то, чем вы запускаете тесты, прячет вывод (но как это исправить, я не знаю, я пользовал только pytest)

Comment: (и да, я имел в виду отпечатать переменную screen, а не строку 'screen')

Comment: @ andreymal Спасибо за помощь. Повыкидывал лишнего и просто добавил строку
driver.save_screenshot('sample_screenshot_1.png')
Сейчас ищу способ как сравнивать два скрина на предмет различий